# Long intervals without $k$-free integers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Inspired by a related question with respect to squarefree integers, I am asking how sharp one can obtain a result of the following type: let $k \geq 2$ be a fixed positive integer. For which functions $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can we conclude that intervals of the type $\left[n, n + \frac{f(n)\log n}{\log \log n}\right]$ contain no number that is $k$-free? That is, every number in the interval is divisible by $p^k$ for some prime $p$.

In this question ([Consecutive non squarefree integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149194/consecutive-non-squarefree-integers)), the case $k=2$ is considered and that $f$ can be taken to be a constant.

Are there any non-trivial improvements (that is, not just an improvement on the constant $c$) for the case $k > 2$?

Comment: If you look at the answer I gave there, you'll find that the paper by McCurley given there considers also $k$-free numbers.  So the same answer given there applies.  By the way, as Erdos notes even an improvement of the constant is nontrivial.