# Square-free numbers in an interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, square-free

Is there an explicit estimate in the literature bounding from above the number of square-free numbers in a short interval $x<n\leq x y$? I can easily do this by means of the Selberg sieve, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x | \mu(n)|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)^2 \approx\frac{6 x}{\pi ^2}+1$ but I'm not sure about the error term. Note that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{| \mu(n)|}{n^s}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2 s)}$ where $\Re(s)>1$, so perhaps there's an error term predicted by the Riemann hypothesis. Note that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)=O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ for every positive $\epsilon$ is equivalent to the RH.

Comment: Notice I am talking about short intervals (i.e. $y = 1+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ may be very small).

Comment: Yes, but the number of square-free numbers in the interval $x<n\le x\, y$ is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{x\, y} |\mu(k)|-\sum\limits_{k=1}^x |\mu(k)|=\sum\limits_{k=x}^{x\, y} |\mu(k)|$, so I was suggesting you search for results associated with the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ (e.g. see some of the results under the Formula section at https://oeis.org/A013928).

Comment: But that leads to *adding* error terms - one won't get an error term better than $O(\sqrt{x})$ that way.

Comment: Ok, I thought it perhaps provided some insight, but I'm not sure if there's a way to get a better result.

Comment: have you seen [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149194)? and would it be possible to clarify what regime of $y$ you are considering?

Comment: @StevenClark Elementary arguments show that $\sum_{n\le x}|\mu(n)|=x/\zeta(2)+O(\sqrt x)$, so there is no need for RH.

Comment: @TravorLZH OEIS entry A013928 indicates Vaidya proved that $\sum\limits_{n\le x}|\mu(n)|=\frac{x}{\zeta(2)}+O(x^k)$ for any $k>\frac{2}{5}$ assuming the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: As this result is unpublished, I still put it here. Selberg's sieve allows one to conclude the number of squarefree integers in $(x,x+u]$ is $\le u/\zeta(2)+O(u^{2/3})$

Comment: Well, sure - up to factors of log, that is clear (but it is nice that there are no factors of log). What is the reference?

Comment: @HAHelfgott The result appears in exercise 6 of section 3.2 of Montgomery & Vaughan's _Multiplicative Number Theory I: Classical Theory_.

Comment: there is also $\# \in (x,x+y)=MT+\mathcal O(x^{1/2+\epsilon })$ in these lecture notes http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~bhowmik/seminaire/GPYZTM.pdf

Comment: Well, sure - just take the difference of the count up to x+y and the count up to x.

Comment: ah, true.. didn't see

Answer (score 3):

Let me just show how to derive a simple bound that has been mentioned in the comments. We are trying to bound the estimate the number $Q(x,x+u)$ of squarefree integers in $(x,x+u]$.

We can now apply Selberg's sieve (as in Iwaniec-Kowalski (say), Thm. 6.4,
with $g(d) = 1/d^2$, $X = u$, $r_d = 2$ and
$|\{x<m\leq x+u: \max \{d: d^2|m\} = n\}|$,
$D$ to be set later).
We obtain
$$Q(x,x+u)\leq
 \frac{u}{H} + 2 \sum_{d\leq D} |\lambda_d|,
 $$
where
$\lambda_d = \sum_{[d_1,d_2]=d} \rho_{d_1} \rho_{d_2}$ and
$|\rho_d|\leq 1$ for all $d$, $\rho_d=0$ for $d>\sqrt{D}$ or $d$ not
square-free, and
$$\begin{aligned} H &= \sum_{d\leq \sqrt{D}} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{\prod_{p|d} p^2 (1-1/p^2)} =
 \sum_{d\leq \sqrt{D}} \mu^2(d) \sum_{m: \textrm{rad}(m)=d} \frac{1}{m^2}\\&\geq
 \sum_{d\leq \sqrt{D}} \frac{1}{d^2} \geq \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} -
 \frac{1}{D}\end{aligned}$$
with $\textrm{rad}(m) = \prod_{p|m} p$. It does not
take much work (just some casework for $D<4$) to show that in fact $H\geq \zeta(2)-1/D$ for $D\geq 1$. Clearly
$\sum_{d\leq D}
 |\lambda_d| \leq \left(\sum_{d\leq \sqrt{D}} \rho_d\right)^2
 \leq D.$ Since $1/H\leq (\zeta(2) (1-1/(\zeta(2) \sqrt{D})))^{-1}$, it follows that
$$\begin{aligned}Q(x,x+u)&\leq \frac{u}{\zeta(2)} + 2 D + \frac{u}{\zeta(2)^2 \left(1- \frac{1}{\zeta(2) \sqrt{D}}\right)\sqrt{D} }\\  &< \frac{u}{\zeta(2)} + 2 D + \frac{u}{\sqrt{D}}.\end{aligned}$$
We set $D = (u/4)^{2/3}$, and obtain
$$Q(x,x+u) < \frac{u}{\zeta(2)} + \frac{3}{2^{1/3}} u^{2/3}.$$

(Please feel free to point how this proof can be made simpler or shorter.)

Comment: Euler product expansion gives $\sum_{d\ge1}{\mu^2(d)\over\prod_{p|d}(p^2-1)}=\prod_p\left(1+{1\over p^2-1}\right)=\zeta(2)$, so there is no need to perform the ordinary lower-bounding trick here.

Comment: Why? We do need a *lower* bound on $H$. We don't have the right to complete the product just like that.

Comment: $H=\zeta(2)-\sum_{d>\sqrt D}{\mu^2(d)\over\prod_{p|d}(p^2-1)}$, and the latter sum might allow you to replace $3\cdot2^{-1/3}$ with a better constant.

Comment: I don't see a simple way (and it's not different from what I was saying). You are right, though, in that that sum should be about 2/(sqrt(D) log D), not 1/sqrt(D).

Comment: One way would be to bound the sum from above by $\sum_{p>\sqrt{D}} 1/p^2$. Estimating that well requires PNT, but I don't see how to obtain the right leading term without using PNT anyhow.

Comment: I meant $\exp( \sum_{p>\sqrt{D}} 1/p^2)$. At any rate, that isn't quite right as an upper bound  - the contribution of higher powers of primes is off - but it goes in the right direction. Surely there has to be an explicit estimate in the literature for this sum ($\sum_{d>z} \mu^2(d)/\prod_{p|d} (p^2-1)$) anyhow. Any takers?

Comment: I'm not sure whether a literature is available for that, but the identity $p^2-1=p^2(1-p^{-2})$ allows one to get something like $$\sum_{d>z}{\mu^2(d)\over d^2}\prod_{p|d}(1-p^{-2})^{-1}<\zeta(2)\sum_{d>z}{\mu^2(d)\over d^2}$$

Comment: Well, sure, but that doesn't help any; it will not give us anything better than $1/\sqrt{D}$ or so.

Comment: BTW - what I said before winning a factor of $\log D$ is not right; of course having $\rad(m)>z$ does not mean that you have no prime factors under $z$.

Comment: One can start with $$\sum_{d>z} \mu^2(d) \sum_{m: \textrm{rad}(m)=d} \frac{1}{m^2} = \sum_{m\; \textrm{sq-full}} \frac{1}{m^2} \mathop{\sum_{d: (d,m)=1}}_{d \textrm{rad}(m) > z} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d^2};$$ this is then roughly $$\begin{aligned} \sum_{m\; \textrm{sq-full}} \frac{1}{m^2} \frac{\prod_{p|m} \frac{1-p}{1-p^2}}{\zeta(2)} \frac{1}{z/\textrm{rad}(m)} &= \frac{z}{\zeta(2)} \sum_{m\; \textrm{sq-full}} \frac{\textrm{rad}(m)}{m^2 \prod_{p|m} (1+1/p)}\\ &=z \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} \prod_{p} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^3 (1+1/p) (1-1/p^2) }\right) \end{aligned}$$ The constant here is indeed $<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Also: see Cohen-Dress, "Estimations numériques du reste de la fonction sommatoire relative aux entiers sans facteurs carrés", 1988 ([https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/Colloque-theorie-analytique-nombres_J.Coquet_1985/pdf/Colloque-theorie-analytique-nombres_J.Coquet_1985.pdf](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/Colloque-theorie-analytique-nombres_J.Coquet_1985/pdf/Colloque-theorie-analytique-nombres_J.Coquet_1985.pdf)), which gives several estimates, none of them strictly better or worse than the one in my answer (each one seems to be best in some range).